# Filter objects that have a timestamp from 2 days ago

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working in apps script . I have a series of objects that have a date_time property that is a timestamp. I want to select all objects that were timestamped 2 days ago only (I don't want 1 day ago or three days ago).

As an example assume today is 3/19/2019. 2 days ago is 3/17/2019. I want all the time stamps that include 3/17/2019

I'm reading https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-date-and-time-in-javascript .

Assuming I have:

```
objs = [{'name':'tom','timestamp':'3/18/2019 11:42:23'},
{'name':'bob','timestamp':'3/19/2019 11:42:23'}, {'name':'dave','timestamp':'3/20/2019 11:42:23'}

]
```

I can get the date from 2 days ago with:

```
var d = new Date();
var 2daysago = d.setDate(d.getDate() - daysAgo);
```

I could then filter with:

```
var filtered = objs .filter(function (obj) {
return X
});
```

What is the best way to compare 2daysago each objects timestamp? would it be better to use date objects or use some kind of string method?

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? What is the relationship between ``objs`` and the image?

Comment: Well, the objects are generated from google sheets rows. I didn't really go into that though.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, all values from Spreadsheet were retrieved and put it to ``objs``. You want to retrieve the required values (in the case of the image, it's ``3/17/2019 10:11:47, 3/17/2019 10:11:49``.) from ``objs`` using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct, assuming today is 3/19/2019.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed 2 patterns as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- At first, all values from Spreadsheet were retrieved and put it to objs.
- You want to retrieve the required values from objs using Google Apps Script.

  - In the case of the image, those are objects of `3/17/2019 10:11:47`, `3/17/2019 10:11:49`, when the today is `3/19/2019`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this answer, I proposed 2 patterns for your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `timestamp` is used as a string. When the today is `3/19/2019`, the values including `3/17/2019` at `timestamp` are retrieved as the values of 2 days ago.

```
var nDaysAgo = 2; // 2 days ago
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
//  var checkDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/dd/yyyy"); // If the day is 01,02,,, please use this.
var checkDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy"); // If the day is 1,2,,, please use this.
var res = objs.filter(function(e) {return e.timestamp.indexOf(checkDate) > -1});
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `timestamp` is used as a date object. When the today is `3/19/2019`, the values from `3/17/2019 00:00:00` to `3/18/2019 00:00:00` are retrieved as 2 days ago.

```
var nDaysAgo = 2; // 2 days ago
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var d1c = d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - nDaysAgo + 1);
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var d2c = d2.setDate(d2.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
var res = objs.filter(function(e) {
  var temp = new Date(e.timestamp).getTime();
  return temp < d1c && temp > d2c;
});
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- If you want to test as `3/19/2019`, please use `new Date("3/19/2019 00:00:00")` instead of `new Date()`.

#### Reference:

- [formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @user61629 I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const oneDayAgo = Date.now() - day;
const twoDaysAgo = Date.now() - 2 * day;

const isTwoDaysOld = function(obj) {
    const d = new Date(obj.timestamp);
    return d > twoDaysAgo && d < oneDayAgo;
}

const filtered = objs.filter(isTwoDaysOld);
```

In JS `Date` is converted to *ms* for numberical operations like `+`, `-`, `>`, `<` etc.

Then all we need to do is find out the point of time (in *ms*) for 2 days ago and the point in time for 1 day ago. And then check if the date in question is in-between.

**Note**: this assumes you mean "24 hours" by "day", not the "day part of the date"

Comment: Its a good answer but I did mean the "day part of the date" - In other words the timestamp that include march 17, assuming today is march 19